# How to redirect from non-www to www in joomla site whith ssl

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, joomla, virtuemart, redirect

I Have a joomla 2.5 & virtuemart 2 eshop.

In www.mysite.com all works perfect ! 
My site redirect from http to https only in checkout area and back in other areas of site (with a Plug-in SSL Redirection).

The problem is if you insert in site with http:/mysite.com in checkout redirect to https://mysite.com/checkout and browser block the page (error: ssl_error_bad_cert_domain)
and say the certificate is only for www.mysite.com !!

How can fix this problem. If i use .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

i thin have problem in ssl area beacause in RewriteRume have http:// ?

The .htaccess inside have

```
##
# @package      Joomla
# @copyright    Copyright (C) 2005 - 2014 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
# @license      GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
##

##
# READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE!
#
# The line just below this section: 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems
# with some server configurations.  It is required for use of mod_rewrite, but may already
# be set by your server administrator in a way that dissallows changing it in
# your .htaccess file.  If using it causes your server to error out, comment it out (add # to
# beginning of line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef url's.  If they work,
# it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need it set here.
##

## Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
Options +FollowSymLinks

## Mod_rewrite in use.

RewriteEngine On

## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
# If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
# This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
#
## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.

## Begin - Custom redirects
#
# If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
# www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
# redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.
#
## End - Custom redirects

##
# Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
# is not directly related to physical file paths.
# Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root).
##

# RewriteBase /

## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the request is for something within the component folder,
# or for the site root, or for an extensionless URL, or the
# requested URL ends with one of the listed extensions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#
## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try add this lines in .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]`

Answer (score 0):

If the browser is complaining, because the certificate is only for www.mysite.com but you want it to use with mysite.com, then the browser is probably right. What you can do is:

- not redirect to https://mysite.com, but to https://www.mysite.com
- or get yourself a certificate for mysite.com (which might include www.mysite.com too)

Comment: Hi ! I don't want use mysite.com but only with www. I want ssl only on checkout area not at all site.

Comment: You cannot rewrite from https://mysite.com to https://www.mysite.com as long as you don't have a valid certificate for mysite.com, because you first need to establish the connection (and thus need a valid certificate) before the redirect can be sent.

Comment: Hi ! I dont want http://example.com to https://www.example.com. I need only http://www.example.com ! I use ssl only in checkout with success.